# Asp.net core web api application, Error occured in startup.cs file

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Error Message:

> Action 'SampleCusAppAPI.Controllers.CustomerController.GetCustomer (SampleCusAppAPI)' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed.

Code: StartUp.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();



            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();  // Error Occured in this line.
            });


        }
```

Web Api code: CustomerController

```
namespace SampleCusAppAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    //[System.Web.Http.Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
    {
        SampleTestingDBContext objSampleTestingDBContext = new SampleTestingDBContext();
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Customer/GetCustomer")]        
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomer()
        {
            return objSampleTestingDBContext.Customers.OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerId);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: the error states clearly about this `GetCustomer(SampleCusAppAPI)`, where is that method? it should be decorated with route attribute

Comment: @king king, Can you send example / Link?

Comment: the example lies right in what you posted, but the code is for `GetCustomer()`, not for `GetCustomer(SampleCusAppAPI)`, so that's why I asked where that method is.

Comment: @king king, I have only one method in my api controller getCustomer(). But error occured like this(GetCustomer(SampleCusAppAPI)). This error occured in app.UseEndpoints.

Comment: @king king Please send me any web api routing example link. I am new to core.

Comment: this looks like a requirement in the new `asp.net core` 3.x+, I'm using `asp.net core 2.2` and don't have such problem. The documentation does not say much about this, the `RouteAttribute` is all you need, I see it's clearly applied on your `GetCustomer()` aciton, so it should work. Unless it means your apply the `RouteAttribute` ***on the controller***, but that's a strange requirement and should have been explained clearly in the documentation. Just try it out.

Comment: when you have this `[Route("api/[controller]")]` applied on the controller, you can apply this `[Route("GetCustomer")]` on your `GetCustomer()` action. Or better apply this `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` on your controller, and apply `RouteAttribute` on your actions only if the name is changed (not the same as the action name).

Comment: I have added an example of an GET api. Please have a look @JoelDharansingh

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of a GET api that you want. It might help you resolve the problem.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get task by id
    /// GET : api/tasks/{id}
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task_id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>        
    [HttpGet("{task_id:long}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long task_id)
    {
        var task = await _taskService.GetTaskByIdAsync(task_id, _user.org_id);
        if (task != null)
        {
            var assignee = await _taskService.GetTaskAssigneeAsync(new long[] { task_id });
            task.assignee = assignee;
            return Ok(task);
        }
        return NotFound(Logger.Error($"No task found with id {task_id}", HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
```